# Data validation of multi-columns table - Formula syntax?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Here's what I am trying to do. I have about 20 people, all with IDs, that have to attend lunchs on different dates. One person can attend only one lunch, they may not go to another one. They may be 5 to 7 people for each lunch

I have structured the table so that columns E to H are the lunch's dates, and under it I will put everyone's IDs.

What is correct way to approach this, if I don't want duplicate entries ?

What I have tried : Data Validation -> Allow: Custom -> Formula: "=COUNTIF(myTable,E2)<=1". It doesn't seem to work, since it finds errors even though an entry hasn't been entered twice (or more).

Thanks!

Comment: Would an assignment model do this for you? See an example here http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/assignment-problem.html

Comment: A picture of what you have would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Interestingly, Excel's Data Validation function do not accept Named Ranges' names
>   within the formula.

So that as long as you think that *"Oh, I've already defined myTable and putted it in the formula, yeah, rocks!"* **unfortunately, that is not working.**

So, to by-pass that issue, I suggest you to define your Range *(which is E2:H8 - because max. attendee number is 7 plus 1 row for header date)* within `Data Validation`. If you would like to create a dynamic range for your table you can use `Offset` as well. Please see my solution below:

### =COUNTIF(OFFSET($E$2,0,0,7,4),E2)=1

Or simply write it like

```
=COUNTIF($E$2:$H$8),E2)=1
```